# How can I install from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I watched github and found interesting for me -> https://github.com/cavneb/Surveyor

How can I install for my own and using it? I don't understand it, when i doing script/plugin install git.  And it appears in my vendor/plugins, and what now?  How i can see it?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Surveyor repository isn't a plugin, it's a full rails application. So your steps are

1. cd Projects (or whatever)
2. git clone https://github.com/cavneb/Surveyor.git
3. cd Surveyor
4. rake gems:install
5. rake db:create
6. rake db:migrate
7. script/server